# A Puzzle Where Trackers Are Truthless

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, knowledge

> I was on a trip and had just got a new phone. I had to get up in the middle of the night to use the bathroom and didn't bother to turn on the light. As I was sitting, my phone rang almost giving me a seizure. I answered immediately but there was no one there. No caller id. Odd. I hadn't given anyone my new number.
>
> Near Granite Hall I stopped to watch my old friend Alvin who was doing his Elvis impersonation in Forsyth Park. While I was watching, someone goosed me! I glanced quickly over my shoulder and saw an attractive young woman. Surely she hadn't... it happened again! I turned around and was about to say something when it happened a third time and I realized it was my phone again. I had put it on vibrate and stuffed it in my back pocket. No one on the line and no caller id.
>
> In Granite Hall I delivered the talk that was the point of the trip. Afterward, I paused to speak to David Lord who was one of the sponsors. DRING DRING DRING DRING! I cut David short. DRING DRING DRING! I fumbled the phone to my ear. Nothing.
>
> At my hotel I plugged in my phone to charge and took a shower. Naturally, I had just stepped in when the phone rang. DRING DRING DRING! *Oh, man!* DRING DRING DRING! *I will kill you for this!* DRING DRING DRING! I leapt for the phone: silence.

But wait, I told that out of order. What is the correct order?

Bonus: who am I?

Clarification: reordering goes by paragraph. I have removed the misleading "again" in the final sentence of a couple of paragraphs. It was meant in the context of "telling in the wrong order" but I can see now it was a bad idea.

Hint:

> None of the incidents are in the correct position. And I changed the title. :-)

Kudos to Gareth McCaughan who solved this puzzle in spite of a series of errors on my part. In his honor I present:

**An Addendum**

The (spoilerish) story of my big stack of blank sheets of paper.

> This happened in the place with a larger entrance where Lamont Cranston and Kent Allard trade tall tales.
>
> DRING! I decided to draw parallel lines on each sheet. DRING! I thought I lost them but after a quick search they turned up.
>
> DRING! I took them to my unlit, windowless basement and made a book out of them!
>
> As I said, this happened in the place with a larger entrance where Lamont Cranston and Kent Allard trade tall tales.

Comment: ... what does goosed mean?

Comment: @WeckarE. "Turned into a goose", obviously.

Comment: These all mirror events taking place in 1893 Boston... but I'm starting to think it is a big coincidence considering the mobile phone...

Comment: @WeckarE. Where did you get Boston? I'm not saying it's not Boston, but maybe you can put a partial answer in?

Comment: @WeckarE. "Goosed" means pinched on the part of your body that you sit on.

Comment: @HughMeyers thank you. I was genuinely puzzled by that :P

Comment: @Weckar Why Boston? The place that stands out to me is Savannah, Georgia, where there is a slightly-famous Granite Hall and a Forsyth Park near to it. (Granite Hall is where Jim Williams from "Midnight in the Garden of Good and Evil" lived.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Boston has both as well, or at the very least used to. And in 1893 both a David Lord and an Alvin Elvis were involved in well-reported court cases, though not the same one.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan. That's exactly where my search hit a dead end.

Comment: @WeckarE. I am not in any way suggesting that you're wrong, but my (purely amateur, googling around on the internet) attempts to find those things have all failed, except that I did find a Forsyth Park in Boston. Where can we find more information?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I punched the info into my university library archive search and it came up with a couple of newspapers in digital form. Not something you could access remotely, I'd reckon...

Comment: Seems too obscure to be part of a fair puzzle, then.

Comment: Not nearly that obscure. Much simpler.

Comment: Good to know it is simpler! Still, with the knowledge tag in place I feel anything is fair game.

Comment: Are you sure the hint is right? The word 'again' in paragraphs 2 and 4 seam to suggest that they are not on the first position. So this leaves 1 in the first position.

Comment: Perhaps whatever rearrangement is needed takes place at a lower level than that of paragraphs.

Comment: @Marius Clarified. Apologies.

Comment: It turns out to be a lot longer ago than 1893.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, Hugh, you are so going to hell for this.

(Apologies if the boldface below is a little too spoilery.)

Near Granite Hall I stopped to watch my old friend **Alvin** who was doing his **Elvis** impersonation in Forsyth **Park**. While I was watching, someone goosed me! I glanced quickly over my shoulder and saw an attractive young woman. Surely she hadn't... it happened again! I turned around and was about to say something when it happened a third time and I realized it was my phone again. I had put it on vibrate and stuffed it in my back pocket. No one on the line and no caller id.

> Three rings for the Alvin Kings under the sky.

In **Granite Hall** I delivered the talk that was the point of the trip. Afterward, I paused to speak to David **Lord** who was one of the sponsors. DRING DRING DRING DRING! I cut David **short**. DRING DRING DRING! I fumbled the phone to my ear. Nothing.

> Seven (rings) for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone.

At my hotel I plugged in my phone to charge and took a shower. Naturally, I had just stepped in when the phone rang. DRING DRING DRING! Oh, **man**! DRING DRING DRING! **I will kill you** for this! DRING DRING DRING! I leapt for the phone: silence.

> Nine rings for mortal men, doomed to die.

I was on a trip and had just got a new phone. I had to get up in the middle of the night to use the bathroom and **didn't bother to turn on the light**. As I was **sitting**, my phone rang almost giving me a seizure. I answered immediately but there was no one there. No caller id. Odd. I hadn't given anyone my new number.

> One (ring) for the Dark Lord on his dark throne.

And evidently you are

> the Dark Lord. Eeeeek!

Oh, the title.

> ... where the shadows (= people shadowing you = trackers) *lie*.

The ordering above doesn't appear to be consistent with what the hint says, but I don't see any possible way that it isn't the right ordering. What's true is that the third paragraph has the correct predecessor and successor.

[EDITED to add:] Since Hugh has kindly added a coda to his puzzle, here is a brief explanation of it for anyone who might still be in, er, the dark.

> ... In the land of More Door where the Shadows lie.
>  One ring to rule them all,
>  One ring to find them,
>  One ring to bring them all
>  and in the darkness bind them,
>  In the land of More Door where the Shadows lie.

Comment: The answer is right and you are probably right about me as well. Can't believe I messed up the hint. Argh! Believe me, my expression is a sour one. Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks. In case it isn't obvious, I thought this puzzle was hilarious.

Comment: Glad you enjoyed. I added a belated Easter egg in your honor.

Comment: I enjoyed the addendum too. Shall I add an explanation of it to my answer?

Comment: Might as well, though it's not like anyone who read the rest of the answer is going to need it. Done.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the question and the answer again, just for the coda. :)  Nice job @HughMeyers and Gareth!